# How to continuously send data to client from server

Tags: bash, shell, tcp, netcat

I want to continuously send data from server to client. On the client side, I only want the received data to be displayed. How to continuously send data to client?
echo "Hello, client!" | nc   did not work.

Thanks in advance

You can see example script of server side below:

```
#!/bin/bash

while true
do
    echo "Sending message to client..."
    echo "Hello, client!" | nc <ip> <port>
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `nc` command is missing `-l` (listen) parameter to behave as a server.

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash

while true
do  
    echo "Sending message to client..."
    echo "Hello, client!" | nc -l 10000
done
```

In another terminal, connect as a client as many times as you want and you'll see the message sent:

```
$ nc localhost 10000
Hello, client!
^C  
$ nc localhost 10000
Hello, client!
^C
```

**EDIT:** To send messages to the client without needing to reconnect, you can create a fifo, make the server read this fifo continuously and forward this data to the client:

```
$ mkfifo fifo_toclient
$ tail -f fifo_toclient | nc -l 10000
```

Run the client side command as before:

```
$ nc localhost 10000
```

In another terminal and in the same directory, modify your script to write data to the pipe instead of directly to `nc` and run it:

```
$ cat send_to_client.sh
#!/bin/bash

while true
do  
    echo "Sending message to client..."
    echo "Hello, client!" > fifo_toclient
    sleep 1
done
$ bash ./send_to_client.sh
```

And you should see the messages in the output of the client side.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
Once the connection is established, I want to send the "hello client" message continuously without needing to connect again and again. Is there a way to this?

Comment: Yes, absolutely. You can do that. Will add this to the answer now.

Comment: Thank you so much. You learned something new to me